# Create dynamic text file with php function

Tags: php, function, dynamic, text, concatenation

So I need to create a dynamic text file based on the name of a variable in php (ex: dynamicName.txt). I then need to write other variables in the file.

```
$testVar = "test.txt";

function sendCalc(){
    global $testVar;
    $objCalcTxt = ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\upload\\$testVar");
    $fp = fopen($objCalcTxt, 'x');
    fwrite($fp, "Test\n");
    fclose($fp);
```

When I do the above, the file is created with no problem, and all the data is written successfully. However, this is not a dynamic file name.

```
$objName = "dynamicName";
$ext = ".txt"
$dynamicNameTxt = $objName.$ext;
function sendCalc(){
    global $objName;
    global $ext;
    global $dynamicNameTxt;
    $objCalcTxt = ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\upload\\$dynamicNameTxt");
    $fp = fopen($objCalcTxt, 'x');
    fwrite($fp, "Test\n");
    fclose($fp);
```

When I try to concatenate the variable that contains the dynamic file name ($objName), with the $ext var, it does not want to create the file.

I echoed the $dynamicName var and it returns dynamicName.txt, so why doesn't this work with fopen. Essentially it has to be a problem with the concatenation right? If so, can I either concatenate a different way, or use a different method to open/create the file?

All help/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really know what you're trying to achieve with the line

```
$objCalcTxt = ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\upload\\$dynamicNameTxt");
```

if from what i understand it should just be a string:

```
$objCalcTxt = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\upload\\".$dynamicNameTxt;
```

Also I'd suggest you provide the needed variables as arguments for the function insted of using `globals`

```
function sendCalc($objName, $ext, $dynamicNameTxt){
...
}
```

Comment: The $objCalcTxt is just to determine the path.

As far as using variables as arguments I'm not quite sure. I was originally using global to make them available in the function to write their values to the text file.

Comment: Well the normal way to achieve such behaviour is to provide them to the function as arguments. And did the suggested change work?

Comment: please try a debug output to see whether the path is correct directly before the `fopen`

Comment: Interesting, here are the 4 error types I'm getting.

Missing argument 1 for sendCalc(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\calcPage.php on line 375 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\calcPage.php on line 332

Comment: Undefined variable: dynamicNameTxt in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\calcPage.php on line 344

Comment: fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\upload\): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\calcPage.php on line 345

Comment: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\calcPage.php on line 346

Comment: well the `fwrite()` results from the `fopen` and the first three are all pretty straightforward to fix. Should not be a problem

Comment: okay the problem with using concatenated variables is fixed. Thanks so much for the help! Unfortunately I discovered that the dynamic variable ($objName) has a problem.

When I attempt to use this variable, defined by:

$objData = new SplFileObject("objData.txt");

$objData->seek(0);
$objName = $objData->current();

It still does not want to run.

Comment: Error: fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\upload\test2-2

.txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\calcPage.php on line 345

Comment: Is this your actual code? a) the string must be in quotes and b) there is a space between the filename and the extension

Comment: I just realized the space. I think the problem is when I take the filename from the first .txt file, its adding a space for some reason...

Comment: Okay removed the space with $objNameArg = substr($objName, 0, -2).".txt"; it's looking good now! Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the global variables inside your function. This could destroy their initial values.
Instead of using global variables in your function, rather pass the variables as arguments:

```
$objName = "dynamicName";
$ext = ".txt"
$dynamicNameTxt = $objName.$ext;
function sendCalc(objName, $ext, $dynamicNameTxt)
{
    $objCalcTxt = ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\upload\\$dynamicNameTxt");
    $fp = fopen($objCalcTxt, 'x');
    fwrite($fp, "Test\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Your other option is to specifically call the global variable:

```
global $objName;
global $ext;
global $dynamicNameTxt;
$objName = "dynamicName";
$ext = ".txt"
$dynamicNameTxt = $objName.$ext;
function sendCalc()
{
    $objCalcTxt = ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\upload\\".$GLOBAL['dynamicNameTxt']);
    $fp = fopen($objCalcTxt, 'x');
    fwrite($fp, "Test\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
```